# How do I use str.format() on a dictionary type?

Tags: python, dictionary

How do I use str.format() on a dictionary type?

For example:

```
>>> a = 'zxv'
>>>
>>> dic = {'a' : 'val = abc', 'b' : 'val = {0}', 'c' : 'val = {0}'}.format(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'format'
```

< This gives an error.

```
>>> dic = {'a' : 'val = abc', 'b' : 'val = {0}'.format(a), 'c' : '{0}'}
>>> dic
{'a': 'val = abc', 'c': '{0}', 'b': 'val = zxv'}
```

< This change makes it viable, but it causes omissions.

Is this a format not supported? Help plz.

I wanted to input multiple values at once using format().
I expected usability similar to the following:

```
>>> a = "hi"
>>> text = ('{0} {0}').format(a)
>>> text
'hi hi'
```

And I'm still using python 2.7.

Comment: What output are you expecting to get?

Comment: One `{}` needs one `.format()` and stay together, this is why your first CODE got an error. As per your second CODE, I didn't get any problem.

Comment: I have revised the question in more detail. I expected to replace n or more {} with a single format(). @Sayse

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```py
dic = {'a': 'val = abc', 'b': f'val = {a}', 'c': 'val = {}'}
```

PS:
it works fine, too.
`dic = {'a': 'val = abc', 'b': 'val = {}'.format(a), 'c': 'val = {}'}`

Answer (score 0):

`format()` is a string method, not a dictionary method.

You can use a loop to call it on each of the  values in the dictionary.

```
dic = {'a' : 'val = abc', 'b' : 'val = {}', 'c' : 'val = {}'}
for key, val in dic.items():
    if `{}` in val:
        dic[key] = val.format(a)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was wondering if this is an unsupported format.
I have revised the content of the question in more detail.